# How to approach configuration as code for Kafka topics in AWS MSK?

Tags: apache-kafka, aws-msk, configuration-as-code

Does AWS MSK support creating topics via configuration, similar what [Strimzi](https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/latest/overview.html#overview-concepts-topic-operator-str) does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can first use [CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-msk-cluster.html) or [Terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/msk_cluster) to create a cluster, or just shell scripts with `awscli`. Maybe also Pulumi or Crossplane (assuming you have k8s), but have not checked.

Then you can use external modules that work with any Kafka cluster to create topics. Such as [this terraform provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/Mongey/kafka/latest/docs/resources/topic), (however, you may need to configure certain auth settings in MSK as I don't think this provider supports IAM configs, for example). Or, if you also have EKS / k8s, you can create topics with Strimzi KafkaTopic operator to still create topics in MSK.

Comment: could you provide links for examples how to do it using CloudFormation and terraform ?

Comment: What difficulty are you having searching for either option?

Comment: not finding the example how to do it..?

Comment: I've added official documentation to my answer